# Custom Angular Validators- Passing an Argument

Tags: angular, validation, ionic-framework

I have followed [Josh Moroney's tutorial](http://www.joshmorony.com/advanced-forms-validation-in-ionic-2/) on creating a custom validator. I got it working, being able to call

newForm.ts

```js
new FormControl(question || '', 
    Validators.compose([AgeValidator.ageIsValid])
);
```

AgeValidator.ts

```js
interface ValidationResult {
  [key: string]: any;
}

export class AgeValidator {
  static ageIsValid(control: AbstractControl): ValidationResult {
    console.log('this is control', control);
    console.log('this is control.value', control.value);

    if (isNaN(control.value)) {
      return {
        notValid: true,
        message: 'this is not a number'
      };
    }
    if (control.value % 1 !== 0) {
      return {
        notValid: true,
        message: 'cant be zero'
      };
    }

    if (control.value < 18) {
      return {
        notValid: true,
        message: 'cant be less than 18'
      };
    }
    if (control.value > 120) {
      return {
        notValid: true,
        message: 'Must be less than 120'
      };
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to add an argument into `.ageIsValid` method, such that I can specify the age that is valid? For example,

```js
new FormControl(question || '', 
    Validators.compose([AgeValidator.ageIsValid(18)])
);
```

What I have tried:

1) Getting rid of `static` and using .ageIsValid like any other method. Result: TS Error

2) Passing an argument like above. Result: Error

Anything else I can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a class with an instance method (instead of static)

```
class AgeValidator {
  constructor(private someParam) {}
  ageIsValid(control: AbstractControl): ValidationResult {
    // use someParam here
  }
}
```

```
var ageValidator = new AgeValidator('foo')
new FormControl(question || '', 
    Validators.compose([ageIsValid.ageIsValid.bind(ageValidator)])
);
```

or a function that returns a function

```
static ageIsValid (someParam) {
  return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationResult => {
    // use someParam here
  }
}
```

```
new FormControl(question || '', 
    Validators.compose([ageIsValid('foo')])
);
```

Comment: Execellent! I went for the second option. The first gave me a bunch of errors (`Can't find control`). The second option seems to work for me now. My only questions is, why do you not need to include `AgeValidator` when calling the method? Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I also prefer the 2nd. I updated the first. This way it should also work if you use `this` inside `ageIsValid()`. I don't know exactly what caused your error.

Comment: The other thing I needed to do was to add a rocket after `ValidationResult` in your second answer. `ValidationResult => {
    // use someParam here
  }` Otherwise TS gave me an error.

Comment: Right, I forgot this when I copied it from the class method. Sorry.